# Is there any difference between a void method that takes a ref type and manipulates it, and a method that returns a ref to the same object

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

Is there much difference between these 2 if the manipulation is identical? In example 1, a reference to an object is passed, and object is manipulated. In example 2, a reference to an object is passed, the object is manipulated, and then... The same reference is returned?

```
static void Foo(SomeReferenceType t)
{
    //Do something with t
}

static SomeReferenceType Foo(SomeReferenceType t)
{
    //Do same thing with t
    return t;
}

Bar bar = new Bar();

//Does this
Foo(bar);
//Do the same thing as this
bar = Foo(bar);
```

Comment: Did you look at the IL produced by both?

Comment: I assume the first line should be `static void Foo(ref SomeReferenceType t)`

Comment: Sorry… I realized it shouldn’t. Peer reviewers: Please discard my edit request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter allows for chaining methods in a fluent type interface, but it can hide the fact that the object is being manipulated.  It's not very common to manipulate an object that's being passed that way because it can confuse consumers of the method when their objects come back mutated.  What you might do is clone the object, manipulate it, and then return the manipulated clone.  This leaves the object in the initial reference intact.

In the former, the consumer is passing a variable and saying, "Dear method, please take this variable and do whatever you want with it including potentially pointing it at a new memory address."  Thus, the developer knows that the state passed in may be manipulated.

By the way, I think you should read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z(v=vs.71).aspx

When I interview potential developers, I ask a lot of questions about passing reference and value types by reference and by value.  I've interviewed developers for very senior level positions who don't understand this but I think it's fundamental to C# development.

Answer (score 1):

This is also a readability issue for me. In addition to some of the other answers already posted, I think returning a SomeReferenceType suggests that the original instance passed in would remain unchanged, and any mutation would be performed on the returned instance (which should be a separate object).  If I was working with this code, I would think the original author was suggesting that I could save a reference to the original type and count on the fact that it would not be mutated.

If the method's only intention is to mutate the object, it should be defined *in* the SomeReferenceType class, so the method and data it modifies are encapsulated together:

```
class SomeReferenceType()
{
  public void Foo()
  {
      // mutate instance here
  }
}

SomeReferenceType a = new SomeReferenceType();
a.Foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

One key conceptual difference could be that a **different** object instance of the same type is returned, that is i.e the case when you executing a method that is "manipulating" an immutable object like a `string` - each method returns a new, different `string` object.

Also of course provided the methods are instance methods (or extension methods) you can chain method calls with the second approach, so you can call additional methods on the returned object instance which makes for a more fluent interaction, i.e.:

```
SomeReferenceType result = obj.Foo()
                              .Bar()
                              .Baz()
```

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Not sure I follow you - in my example I am assuming a *different* object is returned, not the same. I took it as a given if you return the same object the actual reference returned will still point to the exact same location on the heap (even though the actual pointer/reference is different).

Comment: Ignore my comment … deleting.

Answer (score 0):

In that particular case, yes, it does the exact same thing.

For the sake of form, I'd choose the void function rather than the function that returns an object, because if your function returns an object, there's a chance that a person later maintaining your code will assume that the function does create a new instance, leaving the object passed in the parameter unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

The only significant difference that I can see is that in the case of returning the object, you could actually return a different instance of the same class.  But in your example, they're functionally the same